# How to READ local data from Nested Struct using Swift

Tags: swift, struct, swift4

I'm saving and loading data using the following functions and modeling with the following structs, **yet I'm not able to read the array of EntityDat**, not sure if it's because of the **EntityModel Struct** or the call in loading data (**let entityData = try JSONDecoder().decode(EntityModel.self, from: loadedData)**) it's incorrect.

I want my load function to return an array of EntityData which belongs to his parent EntityModel. (e.g. below)

```
 EntityModel {
   {
    "client_name": "John",
    "rut": "70.605.045-5",
    "segment": "Empresa"
   },
   {
    "client_name": "Alex",
    "rut": "60.345.234-1",
    "segment": "Pyme"
   },
   {
    "client_name": "Alice",
    "rut": "12.426.434-5",
    "segment": "Empresa"
   },
}
```

The current output i'm receiving is:
`EntityData:  EntityModel(entidad: nil)`

Save Function:

```
func saveEntityToCoreData2()-> Bool {
        var SavedItem:Bool = true

        var mDictionary : [String: Any] = [
                "client_name": self.clientNameFromCore,
                "rut": self.clientRutFromCore,
                "segment": self.segmentFromCore ]

        let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: mDictionary, options: [.prettyPrinted])
        let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        print("Saved Entity Dictionary", json)

        if self.saveRutSwitchOn
        {
            SecureData.save(key: "entityData", data: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
        }
        SavedItem = self.saveRutSwitchOn

        return SavedItem
    }
```

Load Function:

```
func loadEntityToCoreData2() {
        if let loadedData = SecureData.load(key: "entityData") {
            do {
                let entityData = try JSONDecoder().decode(EntityModel.self, from: loadedData)
                print("EntityData: ", entityData)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

Struct:

```
//Entity Model
struct EntityModel: Codable {
    let entidad: [EntityData]!
}

struct EntityData: Codable {
    let client_name: String!
    let rut: String!
    let segment: String!
}
```

Comment: The JSON is not valid. Unrelated but never declare members of structs conforming to `Codable` as implicit unwrapped optional. Don't do that. Either declare them as non-optional (recommended in your case) or regular optional (`?`). And never print `error.localizedDescription` in a `DecodingError` catch block. Print always `error`.

Comment: @vadian thank you for your input. Do you mind explaining the last suggestion? Why it's not good to print **error. localizedDescription** ?

Comment: Because with `error.localizedDescription` you get generic *The data could not be read because it is in the wrong format* message. With `error` you get a comprehensive error message about the exact kind of the error and the location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct json

```
[
   {
    "client_name": "John",
    "rut": "70.605.045-5",
    "segment": "Empresa"
   },
   {
    "client_name": "Alex",
    "rut": "60.345.234-1",
    "segment": "Pyme"
   },
   {
    "client_name": "Alice",
    "rut": "12.426.434-5",
    "segment": "Empresa"
   }
]


struct EntityModel: Codable {
  let clientName, rut, segment: String 
}
```

---

```
 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
 decoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase
 let entityData = decoder.decode([EntityModel].self, from:data)
```

---

when you save , make it an array like

```
var arr : [[String: Any]] = [[
            "client_name": self.clientNameFromCore,
            "rut": self.clientRutFromCore,
            "segment": self.segmentFromCore ]]
```